# Famoso erro: Erro de conversão ao definir o valor XXX para 'null Converter'

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee, front-end

Boa tarde.

Estou com o famoso erro "Erro de conversão ao definir o valor XXX para 'null Converter'." já vi vários tópicos aqui mesmo e em outros foruns, Showcase do primefaces e não consegui resolver (em partes). Na minha aplicação Tem um cadastro de usuário, dentro dele tenho que salvar uma Equipe (é como se fosse uma empresa terceirizada) por um SelectOneMenu mas na hora de salvar dá o famoso erro. Bom vou colocar os códigos:

Aqui é só o método do **Dao** que lista as equipes e **EquipeDao:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Equipe> listar(){
        EntityManager manager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("APRSAS").createEntityManager();
        javax.persistence.Query q =  (javax.persistence.Query) manager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Equipe e");
        List<Equipe> equipes = ((javax.persistence.Query) q).getResultList();

        return equipes;
    }
```

Aqui o **Bean** do **Usuario:**

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="userId", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name="ativo")
    private boolean ativo;

    @Column(name="userNome")
    private String userNome;

    @Column(name="login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name="senha")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Equipe equipe;  

    @Column(name="permissaoAcesso")
    private int permissaoAcesso;    

//get set .....
}
```

A classe responsável em carregar a **lista**:

```
@ManagedBean(name="equipeService", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class EquipeService {

    private List<Equipe> equipes;
    EquipeDao equipedao = new EquipeDao();  

    public List<Equipe> getEquipes() {
            equipes = equipedao.listar();
        return equipes;
    }
}
```

Depois do erro descobri que tinha que criar um **converter**, então peguei esse do **showcase** do **Primefaces**:

```
@FacesConverter("equipeConverter")
public class EquipeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                EquipeService service = (EquipeService) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("equipeService");
                return service.getEquipes().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERRO AO CARREGAR EQUIPES", "Equipe não encontrada."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((Equipe) object).getEquipeId());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

E o pedaço do **xhtml** que tem o **selectonemenu**:

```
<p:outputPanel id="displayEquipe1">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Equipe:"
                        rendered="#{usuarioAddEditMB.usuario.permissaoAcesso == '3'}" />
                </p:outputPanel>
                <p:outputPanel id="displayEquipe2">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="Equipe"
                        value="#{usuarioAddEditMB.usuario.equipe}"
                        converter="equipeConverter"
                        rendered="#{usuarioAddEditMB.usuario.permissaoAcesso == '3'}"
                        style="width:125px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="#{null}" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{equipeService.equipes}" var="equipe"
                            itemLabel="#{equipe.equipeNome}" itemValue="#{equipe}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:outputPanel>
```

(obs. ignorem aquele rendered, é só uma regra de negocio)

Depois que eu criei o **conveter** não carregava mais a pagina e começou aparecer esse erro: **java.lang.String cannot be cast to** ... mas em um tópico em um outro forum vi que tinha que colocar um **null** no `itemValue`, fiz isso e a pagina voltou a carregar, so que agora quando eu mando salvar dá um erro , mas no console só aparece escrito **NULL**, não sei mas o que fazer para arrumar isso.

**Editado:**

> Por gentileza, coloque o erro assim como está impresso no log. Para,
>   por exemplo, ver qual método está disparando a exceção. @Luídne

Tirei do itemvalue o "#{null}" e deixei só as aspas, apareceu esse erro:

```
Abr 09, 2017 5:36:13 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to br.com.sistemaaprsas.bean.Equipe
    at br.com.sistemaaprsas.converter.EquipeConverter.getAsString(EquipeConverter.java:34)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getOptionAsString(InputRenderer.java:164)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeOption(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:345)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeSelectItems(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:331)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeInput(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:114)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:91)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:65)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:74)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(OutputPanelRenderer.java:64)
    at org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputPanelRenderer.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1864)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at br.com.sistemaaprsas.filter.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java
```

EDITADO 2:

Eu tenho uma busca por **ID** no **DAO**:

```
public Equipe getById(int equipeid) {
        EntityManager manager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("APRSAS").createEntityManager();
        Equipe equipe = null;
        try{

            equipe =  manager.find(Equipe.class, equipeid);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return equipe;      
    }
```

Acabei mudando meu converter conforme pesquisas, cheguei nesse resultado:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
    if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
        try {
            return new EquipeDao().getById(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERRO AO CARREGAR EQUIPES",
                    "Equipe não encontrada."));
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
    if (object != null && object instanceof Equipe) {
        return ((Equipe) object).getEquipeId().toString();
    }
    return null;

}
```

mas agora entra  no throw:

```
throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERRO AO CARREGAR EQUIPES",
                        "Equipe não encontrada."));
```

Comment: Por gentileza, coloque o erro assim como está impresso no log. Para, por exemplo, ver qual método está disparando a exceção.

Comment: ok, já vou postar

Comment: Então, como eu falei, nesse codigo que eu postei o unico erro que parece no console é `null` não aparece mais nenhum erro.

Comment: no itemvalue tirei o o valor `#{null}` e deixei só as aspas apareceu esse erro:

Comment: Imprima no log ou no `throw` em getAsObject() o valor do parâmetro `String value`. Pra vermos o porquê da exceção.

Comment: Opa @Luídne eu fiz o out.printl do value e ele me mostra o valor do itemLabel e não do itemValue, e fiz o e.printStackTrace(); e tambem me da o valor do itemLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um amigo me passou um converter que deu certo, funcionou perfeito segue:

```
@FacesConverter("equipeConverter")
public class EquipeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {

        if (value == null || value.equals(""))
            return null;
        try {
            Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
            Collection items = (Collection) uic.getAttributes().get("items");
            return findById(items, id);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ConverterException("Não foi possível aplicar conversão de item com valor [" + value
                    + "] no componente [" + uic.getId() + "]", ex);
        }

        /*
         * if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) { try { return new
         * EquipeDao().getById(Integer.parseInt(value)); } catch
         * (NumberFormatException e) { throw new ConverterException(new
         * FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERRO AO CARREGAR EQUIPES",
         * "Equipe não encontrada.")); } } else { return null; }
         */
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null)
            return "";
        return getIdByReflection(value).toString();
    }

    private Object findById(Collection collection, Long idToFind) {
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            Long id = getIdByReflection(obj);
            if (id == idToFind)
                return obj;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Long getIdByReflection(Object bean) {
        try {
            Field idField = bean.getClass().getDeclaredField("equipeId");
            idField.setAccessible(true);
            return (Long) Long.valueOf(idField.get(bean).toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Não foi possível obter a propriedade 'equipeId' do item", ex);
        }
    }

}
```